# How to edit value at the end of for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I run the function below to fetch product Infos, I save every request on array, very basic API stuff

```js
fetch = id => {
  var url = "https://myapi.server.com";
  var request = new Request(url + "/api/v1/fetch/", {
    method: "POST"
  });
  fetch(request)
    .then(response => {
      response.json().then(results => {
        this.setState({
          items: this.state.items.concat([results.data])
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    });
};
```

to init this function it runs inside for loop like so

```js
var favs = JSON.parse(value);
for (let x in favs) {
  this.fetch(favs[x].id);
}
```

if I add setState loading: false in the function it will show data on screen and mess things up, I wish to wait until the array is done I have tried the approach below but it kinda funky, it doesn't work, the logic seems right to me

```js
var length = favs.length - 1;
for (let x in favs) {
  this.fetch(favs[x].id);
  if (x === length) {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }
}
```

If anyone can assist, please any suggestion appreciated

Comment: `fetch()` is **asynchronous**. Your loop will complete long before the requests do

Answer (score 2):

You can organize your data into array of promises and use Promise all, so state will be set only after all data is loaded:

```
Promise.all(favs.map((item) => this.fetch(item.id))).then(() => { 
    this.setState({loading: false})
})
```

Comment: I tried this sir it's not working, at least how I did it

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to recognize last iteration, this is one of the ways:

```js
const favs = [1,2,3,4,5]; // or var favs = JSON.parse(value)
let counter = 0;
for(let x in favs) {
    counter++;
    console.log( counter==favs.length ? "last one" : "not last" );
    console.log(x);
    /*
    if (counter==favs.length) {
       this.setState({loading: false})
    }
    */

}
```

In your example, you compared x (which is probably object) to a number.

Comment: That was my first guess, too. I suggested to simply run the code after the loop, but the problem is that fetch is async :P

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work beacuse this.fetch is an asyncronous function. So you basically start n calls and you don't wait for them to finish before set the loading to false;

I'll suggest a little refactoring.

The Promise.all function might be your answer.

```
fetch = (id) => {
    var url = 'https://myapi.server.com'
    var request = new Request(url + '/api/v1/fetch/', {
      method: 'POST',
    })
    return fetch(request)
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err.message)
      })
  }
.
.
.


 var favs = JSON.parse(value)
 var fetchCalls = favs.map(fav => this.fetch(fav.id));

Promise.all(fetchCalls).then((results) => {
    this.setState({
            items: [...results.data] // or items: [...items,...result.data]
          });
    this.setState({loading: false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about the `===` operator here - so why not simply call it after the loop?

```
for (let x in favs) {
  this.fetch(favs[x].id)
}
this.setState({loading: false})
```

it's easier to read and should work.

**Edit**: as `fetch()` is asynchronous, you need a different approach:

```
// somewhere outside the function
var fetchCount = favs.count;

// in your function
for (let x in favs) {
  this.fetch(favs[x].id).then(decreaseFetchCount());
}

// define this somewhere outside
function decreaseFetchCount ()
{
   fetchCount -= 1;
   if(fetchCount == 0)
       this.setState({loading: false})
}
```

Comment: This might not work as expected, because `fetch` is async and once the loop gets executed even before getting the response `loading` will be set to `false`.

Comment: Thanks, I added a 2nd version with should work with the asynchronous fetch.

Comment: This is a really really bad idea. Never ever use a counter to track how many async calls have been completed... simply use callbacks or simply use `await Promise.all([promises])`.

Comment: Reason being, if one of your fetch calls fails, the `then` won't be executed, therefore your state will permanently be `loading`.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but i think you are looking for something like this

https://www.techup.co.in/react-native-pagination-example-infinity-list/

Promise.all will not be optimal solution if data size is large

Comment: yes but it's a different implementation I just want to keep my code at it is